# Have a constant parameter in all my django URLs

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a django website that shows data which is seperated in 3 differents databases corresponding to different servers.
I have a dropdown list on my website that allow to choose the desired server.
What i would like is when a server is chosen, that this choice is keeped all around the website until an other server choice is done.
With this choice beeing constant in the URLs like that : `website.com/server1/home` -> `website.com/server1/page-1` -> *new server choice* -> `website.com/server2/page-1`

I don't know how to keep this parameter constant without having to pass a variable '`server_name`' to every view and every URL of my website.

Is there an easier way to do this ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: IDK how to use but I know that the solution for you is django sessions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/